# Hashset contains with exact character placement and incorrect character placement

Tags: java, contains, hashset

I have a class that determines how many matching characters are in 2 char arrays. Using the `HashSet` contains method, if one char array contains a Character from the second array, display the character.
The problem is if we have two matching characters appearing in multiple locations.

For example, if `array 1 = adcd` and `array 2 = a05ddd`, `d` appears 3 times, not 2.
How would I modify this to account for the correct character count? The code produces `"addd"` when it should produce `"add"`
For the incorrect characters, the result would be
`"a--dd"`

```
    HashSet<Character> hash = new HashSet<Character>();        
    String word1 = "adcd";
    String word2 = "a05ddd";
    char[] ch1 = word1.toCharArray();
    char[] ch2 = word2.toCharArray();
    Character character = null;
    String charLocation = "";
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < ch1.length; i++) 
    {
        hash.add(ch1[i]); 
       
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ch2.length; i++) 
    {
        character = ch2[i]; 
        if (hash.contains(character)) 
           {
            charLocation = charLocation + character;
             count++;
            } 
        if (!hashSet.contains(character)) 
            correctCharPlacements = correctCharPlacements + "-";
    }
```

Comment: FYI, the `char` and `Character` types in Java are obsolete, unable to represent even half the characters defined in Unicode. Learn about [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codepoint) integer numbers used to represent each character.

Comment: How about the case when the second line has only 1 character `d` (`"a05d123"`), should the `common` result be `ad` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that the data about the frequency of the characters needs to be collected -- so set should be replaced with a map.  Then the resulting string may be built with regard to common characters **and** minimal frequency of the character in both words:

```java
// helper method to build frequency map for a word/string
private static Map<Character, Integer> freqMap(String word) {
    return word.chars()
               .mapToObj(c -> (char)c)
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, x -> 1, Integer::sum, LinkedHashMap::new));
}

static String common(String w1, String w2) {
    if (null == w1 || null == w2) {
        return null;
    }
    Map<Character, Integer> map1 = freqMap(w1);
    Map<Character, Integer> map2 = freqMap(w2);
    Set<Character> commonChars = new LinkedHashSet<>(map1.keySet());
    commonChars.retainAll(map2.keySet());

    return commonChars.stream()
                      .map(x -> String.valueOf(x).repeat(Math.min(map1.get(x), map2.get(x))))
                      .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
}
```

Test:

```java
System.out.println("common = " + common("adcd", "a05ddd"));
```

Output:

```
common = add
```

---

**Update**

As [`String::repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) is available starting from Java 11, it may be replaced with the Java 8 compatible code using `String::join` + `Collections.nCopies`:

```java
    static String common(String w1, String w2) {
        if (null == w1 || null == w2) {
            return null;
        }
        Map<Character, Integer> map1 = freqMap(w1);
        Map<Character, Integer> map2 = freqMap(w2);
        Set<Character> commonChars = new LinkedHashSet<>(map1.keySet());
        commonChars.retainAll(map2.keySet());
 
        return commonChars.stream()
                          .map(x -> String.join("", Collections.nCopies(Math.min(map1.get(x), map2.get(x)), String.valueOf(x))))
                          .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
    }
```

[Online demo](https://onlinegdb.com/S1gr3Z7cw):

```java
System.out.println("Java version: " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
System.out.println("common = " + common("adcd", "a05ddd"));
```

Output:

```
Java version: 1.8.0_201
common = add
```

---

**Update 2**

In order to keep the order of the characters in the second string in the result and replace missing characters with `'-'`, the following method can be implemented:

```java
static String common2(String w1, String w2) {
    if (null == w1 || null == w2) {
        return null;
    }
    Map<Character, Integer> map1 = freqMap(w1);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : w2.toCharArray()) {
        if (map1.containsKey(c) && map1.get(c) > 0) {
            sb.append(c);
            map1.merge(c, -1, Integer::sum); // decrement the character counter in the first map
        } else if (!map1.containsKey(c)) { // character missing in the first word
            sb.append('-');
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Tests

```java
String[][] tests = {
    {"adcd", "ad05dd"},
    {"adcd", "d05add"},
    {"adcd", "d05dadd"},
};
for (String[] test : tests) {
    System.out.printf("common(%s, %s) = %s%n", test[0], test[1], common(test[0], test[1]));
}
```

Output:

```
common(adcd, ad05dd) = ad--d
common(adcd, d05add) = d--ad
common(adcd, d05dadd) = d--da
```

Comment: Hi, I get the error "Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R>)". I thought this was an eclipse bug so I tried this in BlueJ and on the command line, still get the same error. How would I go about this? I also edited the post a bit if you don't mind as I appreciate the help you gave.

Comment: Which version of Java / JDK are you using?

Comment: JavaSE -1.8 (jdk- 11.0.1)

Comment: Updated with Java 8 compatible version, `String::repeat`  available starting from Java 11

Comment: Thank You. If I wanted to keep the order of the characters, how would I do so? I tried a Linked map but that didn't work since the code is joining all like characters together if I'm correct. (I'm going to look up each of these methods used later today to actually understand how this is put together). Mind if I reply to this comment tomorrow with a writeup of what I believe the code is doing and you can check if I'm right?

Comment: Do you need to keep the _alphabet_ order of the characters, or the order of characters in the second string?  You should provide more examples (input and expected output)

Comment: Order of the characters in the second string.

Comment: Thank You so much. I would like to understand how to that frequency method works as I haven't much knowledge on Collect and I would like to know more. From looking up each method:                                                                               So the frequency method takes the String, converts it to a stream with the chars() method. 
mapToObj converts that to a char 
so that we can read it. 
.collect(Collectors.toMap coverts the String to a map. I don't understand how though. How does this
(x -> x, x -> 1, Integer::sum, LinkedHashMap::new)) convert the String to a map.

Comment: For the common method:
.Stream converts our Hashset to a stream. 
          .map(x -> String.join("" I beleive this just adds the map to a string
Collections.nCopies This adds a copy of the minimum size of the map needed.
.collect(Collectors.joining("")) This connects all the characters together.